# selected value in bootstrap select

Tags: angular, typescript

i have data saved in my localestorage, i want selected option to be data i have in my `this.data.period` which is 5, how can i do that?

i made [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-starter-ditztm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) but without localestorage

**.html**

```
   <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="period">
        <option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="this.data.period">{{year.year}}</option>
      </select>
```

**.ts**

```
  years = [
    {
    year: 3,
    value: 3,
  },
  {
    year: 4,
    value: 4
  },
  {
    year: 5,
    value: 5
  },
  {
    year: 6,
    value: 6
  },
  {
    year: 7,
    value: 7
  },
  {
    year: 8,
    value: 8
  },
  {
    year: 9,
    value: 9
  },
  {
    year: 10,
    value: 10
  },
]

  get data(): any {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
  }

 console.log(this.data.period); // 5
```

Comment: localestorage? What is that? Do you really mean `localStorage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="period">
    <option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year.value">{{year.year}}</option>
  </select>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</form>
```

```
export class OneComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {


  constructor() {
    // simulation
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify({period: 5}));
  }

  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    period: new FormControl('')
  });

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.profileForm.get('period')?.valueChanges.subscribe((res: string) => {
      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify({period: res}));
    })
  }

  years = [
    {
      year: 3,
      value: 3,
    },
    {
      year: 4,
      value: 4
    },
    {
      year: 5,
      value: 5
    },
    {
      year: 6,
      value: 6
    },
    {
      year: 7,
      value: 7
    },
    {
      year: 8,
      value: 8
    },
    {
      year: 9,
      value: 9
    },
    {
      year: 10,
      value: 10
    },
  ];


  ngOnInit() {
     // Initialize the setting values
    let a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data') as string);
    (this.profileForm.get('period') as FormControl).setValue(a.period)

  }
}
```